# Convert python faker dict type to json object

Tags: python, json, flask, faker

I am trying to create mock data and return them in json format via API with Python faker package but not sure how to convert the faker object into json format correctly. Here are the function used for the mock data generation:

```py
import json
from flask import Flask, request
from json import dumps, loads, JSONEncoder
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import person
import random

fake = Faker()
fake.add_provider(person)

### ensure the name and gender matched
def first_name_and_gender():
    g = 'M' if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else 'F'
    n = fake.first_name_male() if g=='M' else fake.first_name_female()
    return {'gender':g,'first_name':n}

d = dict()
d['first_name_and_gender'] = first_name_and_gender
d['last_name'] = lambda: {'last_name':fake.last_name()}

def returnMockdata(numRows):
    dict_new=dict()
    dict_new["User"]={}
    key=[]
    json_str={}

    ### loop to generate <numrows> mock data
    for _ in range(numRows):
        value_list = [d[k]().values() for k in d.keys()] 

        if len(key) == 0:
            key_list =  [d[k]().keys() for k in d.keys()] 
            key=[item for sublist in key_list for item in sublist] ## iterate and put keys into a list

        value=[item for sublist in value_list for item in sublist] ## iterate and put values into a list

        value_new = zip(key,value) ## combine key and value
        dict_new["User"].update( dict( (name,value) for name,value in value_new)) ## append the dict

        json_str=json.dumps(dict_new) ## convert dict to json object

        print(json_str) ## output in the console window

    return json_str
```

Here are the API call program:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from f_mockdata2 import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/mockdata/<int:number>')
def returnMock(number):
    return returnMockdata(number)
```

When submit the following request:
http://localhost:5000/api/mockdata/5

The json_str will be output in console as follows:

```
{"User": {"gender": "F", "first_name": "Andrea", "last_name": "Gibson"}}
{"User": {"gender": "M", "first_name": "Anthony", "last_name": "Neal"}}
{"User": {"gender": "F", "first_name": "Elizabeth", "last_name": "Sandoval"}}
{"User": {"gender": "M", "first_name": "Jonathan", "last_name": "Brown"}}
{"User": {"gender": "F", "first_name": "Cheryl", "last_name": "Mcpherson"}}
```

But only the final record to be returned in the browser window.

```
{"User": {"gender": "F", "first_name": "Cheryl", "last_name": "Mcpherson"}}
```

I understand the output json_str was not a valid jason and there must be something wrong or other better option to derive the output in json format. Any thoughts to fix would be highly appreciated.

Thanks very much!
Stanley

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-faker-library/) can help you

Comment: You replaced json_str every time in your loop. Logically this will return the last result of the set. Create one big dictionary before creating your json and return the json of this big object.

Comment: Thanks Amin@AminGuermazi, that's helpful. Since sub function derived and nested dict created in my scenario, so I cannot follow that solution directly, still thinking what's the best way instead.

Comment: Thanks @Wimanicesir for pointint that out, it's supposed dict_new["User"].update will return the concatenated list of the results but seems not the truth, any advice for that?

Comment: Just fixed by changing the `dict_new["User"]` to `dict_new[k]=dict( (name,value) for name,value in value_new)`, in addition, the for loop need to be changed as `for k in range(0, numRows):` as well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found the solution! :)